# Laravel form validtor with array field and numeric validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am making a form having 2 fields unit_id and price.

```
<select name="unit_id[]">...</select>
<input name="price[]" />
```

Note: I have 5 sets of the above 2 lines in the form.

On the other hand my validator looks like this -

```
$request->validate([
    'price' => 'required|array',
    'price.*' => 'numeric|min:0|max:9999',
    'unit_id' => 'required|array',
]);
```

Now I am getting this error, due to the numeric validation -

```
TypeError
htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given
```

Request POST dump looks like this -

```
array:2 [▼
  "price" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "20"
    1 => "abcd"
  ]
  "unit_id" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "4"
  ]
]
```

Any idea about how to validate and force each price field to be of numeric?

Comment: is `"abcd"` supposed to be a numerical price ?

Comment: Yes, thus, the validation should stop it from going into the DB

Answer (score 0):

this problem is for the value of the input and maybe when you use blade elements in the dom element the content has the wrong structure and made this problem.
in some cases, double quotes can't convert correctly when using json_encode or json_decode, and cause of this error.